# Cannot add/get Cache File correctly with Hadoop 3.0.0-alpha2

Tags: java, hadoop

I am a beginner of Hadoop. I was working on the WordCountV2 given by [Apache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v2.0).

My IDE showed `method addCacheFile not found in class Job` when I was trying to use `Job.addCacheFile(new Path(remainingArgs[++i]).toUri());`

I Googled a bit and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) is the only one I could find but there's no solution in it.

I am not sure why this happened (`getCacheFiles` works well for me). I guess there's something to do with how I set up the environment? (Unfortunately new to Java as well).

I am using Eclipse+Maven and the `pom.xml` is setup as:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

May I ask if it is possible that the error is caused by my setup, while if not what could be the reason?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce what you have tried and did not encountered any kind of problem. I am using MRv2.

From the pom, it seems you are using MR2 ( which is the latest ). So remove the MR1 dependency(hadoop-core 2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.10.1). The hadoop core jar is not required for MRv2.

The code I have used. This should work if you are using MRv2.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);

        job.addCacheFile(new Path("").toUri());
    }
}
```

But if you want to use MRv1, then we need to change the POM, then we need to use

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("<path to file>"), conf);

    Job job = new Job(conf);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize what `mr1` stands for and I was wondering why maven's hadoop-core version is divergent from others. I replaced the `hadoop-core` dependency with `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core(3.0.0-alpha2)` and removed `hadoop-core` in `.m2/repo`. Now everything works well.